# Installing azure-cli on macOS results in "Failed writing body" and "image not found" errors

Tags: macos, azure-cli

I want to install azure-cli on a MacOS (10.12.5) computer. 
Python 2.7.13 is installed (was installed using homebrew, some time ago, but updated today). Xcode command line tools are installed.

I am following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli

There's really not much to it. Just run this command:
`curl -L https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCli | bash`

But when I run that command, I get this result:

```
 j-mbp:~ jonathan$ curl -L https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCli | bash
 dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
 Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/bash
 Reason: image not found
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100   167  100   167    0     0     47      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--    77
    100  1367  100  1367    0     0    219      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--   653
 (23) Failed writing body
 Abort trap: 6
```

I have no idea what this error means, and there is no information in the instructions related to possible issues.

Can you tell me how to proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this error code, please **upgrade** your bash with this command `brew upgrade bash` then re-run this script `curl -L https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCli | bash`.

Comment: Thanks Jason. That's exactly what I discovered a few hours ago, and it resolved the issue, and numerous other issues I was having with various scripts, etc.,